# How to make all result appear

Tags: python, selenium

```
import sys

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
import time



def main():
    driver = configuration()
    motcle = sys.argv[1]
    recherche(driver,motcle)

def configuration():
    """
    Permet de faire la configuration nécessaire pour faire le scrapping
    :return: driver
    """

    path = "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
    return driver
def recherche(driver,motcle):
    actionChain = ActionChains(driver)
    search = driver.find_element_by_id("search")
    search.send_keys(motcle)
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    content =  driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#contents ytd-item-section-renderer>div#contents a#thumbnail')
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    links = []
    for item in content:
        links+= [item.get_attribute('href')]
    print(links)

    time.sleep(5)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My program works but not entirely or as expected. I want to have all links but only 4 appear. I tried to use WebDriverWait but it is not working either. I tried to make the program wait too but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `driver.find_elements` with defined `driver.implicitly_wait` waits for presence of at least 1 web element matching the passed locator and then this occurs it immediately returns the list of the web elements matching that locator.
It doesn't wait for all the elements matching that locator.
Exactly the same issue is with expected conditions `EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located`.
What I can advice you here is to use expected conditions to get the first element presented, then set some sleep to make all the other elements to load and then to get the list of elements.
So you code will look like following:

```
import sys

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
import time



def main():
    driver = configuration()
    motcle = sys.argv[1]
    recherche(driver,motcle)

def configuration():
    """
    Permet de faire la configuration nécessaire pour faire le scrapping
    :return: driver
    """

    path = "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
    return driver
def recherche(driver,motcle):
    actionChain = ActionChains(driver)
    search = driver.find_element_by_id("search")
    search.send_keys(motcle)
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div#contents ytd-item-section-renderer>div#contents a#thumbnail')))
    time.sleep(5)
    content =  driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#contents ytd-item-section-renderer>div#contents a#thumbnail')
    links = []
    for item in content:
        links+= [item.get_attribute('href')]
    print(links)

    time.sleep(5)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, it's not advised to use `driver.implicitly_wait` at all and if you still wish to use it there is no need to define if again and again. Once defined it is defined for the entire session of the web driver.

Comment: Yes, perfectly Thanks a lot.

Comment: If so please accept the answer. BTW it will give you 2 points too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate over it directly and add an `explicit wait` it should pull in all the items you are looking for

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

links = []

for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div#contents ytd-item-section-renderer>div#contents a#thumbnail'))):
    links.append(item.get_attribute('href'))
```

You can get rid of the `implicity_wait` calls

I tested this with the search word "Python" and it pulled in all 25+ href links into the list

Comment: You are not right! expected condition `visibility_of_all_elements_located` works exactly like  the `find_elements` with the `implicitly_wait`: once it founds at least 1 element matching the passed locator it returns a list of caught elements!

Comment: @Prophet  Well, it worked fine for me and his code did not.  You are the genius here though, so I hope you get the points you crave

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't intend to hurt you. Just wished to teach you some point you possibly still not know. Also I'm very far from being a genius. I see a lot of people much professional and smart than me here.

Comment: BTW I didn't get points for that answer at all :)